# Как выбрать строку с максимальным id

Tags: mysql, sql

Как выбрать строку с максимальным `id` где в колонке `page` будет `poll`

Пробовал вот так `SELECT MAX(id) FROM wall`

Всё хорошо, но мне нужно что бы выбрало строку где в параметре `page` будет `poll`

Comment: Странно, что такой очевидный вопрос и до сих пор не встретился на сайте... Не нашёл подходящую закрывашку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы захотели дать ответ на свой вопрос, он видимо решает вашу конкретную проблему. Но его минусуют, а другой ответ - плюсуют. В чём дело?

> Программист -- это чёткость ума и точность формулировок.

Если бы вы сформулировали задачу как "найти идентификатор строки с максимальным..." -- то ваш ответ блестяще бы подошёл под условия задачи. Да, бывает, что некоторые начинающие не знают о существовании конструкции where и спрашивают про неё. Вот такой ответ был бы достаточным и полным:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM wall WHERE page='poll'
```

Но.. вы написали "Как выбрать строку с максимальным" и даже вынесли это в заголовок. И такое (на ваш взгляд) незначительное изменение кардинально меняет суть вопроса (для отвечающих).

От своей конструкции вы не перейдёте к тому, чтобы выбрать всю строку или часть полей строки. А вот ответ @Naumov в этом плане красив, точен и делает именно то, что спрашивают:

```
SELECT * FROM `wall` WHERE `page` = "poll" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Я вообще почему взялся дописывать ответ, хотя уже есть два ответа сразу на два вопроса? Дело вот в чём.

Если у вас есть два сервера, на одном крутится sql-сервер, а на другом - клиент (и даже в случае если это один и тот же сервер), то наша задача - беречь ОЗУ буферов в памяти, через которые сервер отдаёт клиенту данные (передать два поля таблицы по сети или двадцать два - есть разница), беречь трафик по сети (передавать одну строку или миллион строк) и количество подключений (это время, тормоза).

Для чего вам нужен этот ID? Пользователю сайта не нужны ID, ему нужны другие поля таблицы. Самым неразумным будет получить на клиенте этот max(id) с сервера и тут же полезть следующим запросом выбирать все поля SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = полученый id.

Даже такой громоздкий запрос будет лучше с точки зрения того, что бережёт соединения и уменьшает общее время работы:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM wall WHERE page='poll')
```

Но это менее оптимальный запрос, чем ответ, который вам уже дал Наумов, можете посмотреть план выполнения запроса через explain.

Поэтому я рекомендую принять именно его версию, а не вашу. Альтернативно можно было бы переписать формулировку вопроса и принять его. Но я не уверен, что вам охота будет столько заморачиваться - а главное, я думаю, что для будущих посетителей оставить именно такую версию вопроса, потому что именно по таким запросам и будут гуглить впоследствии.

Итого, небольшая сводка:

> Желательно чётко понимать, что вам нужно: либо только id либо вся строка.

Надеюсь, информация из моего ответа поможет сделать более осознанный выбор.

Comment: Надеюсь, правильно подправил?

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * FROM `wall` WHERE `page` = "poll" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Логика проста выбираем, сортируем по убыванию и берём 1-ю строку.

Comment: И легкий штрих - наложить `where page= 'poll'`. Добавьте, мне кажется топик стартер не понимает основ языка запросов.

Comment: по убыванию....

Comment: @teran Я просто всегда путаю "убыване" с "возрастанием", "ужин" с "завтраком" такая уж особеность.

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо получить *только идентификатор строки* — то вполне подойдёт и такая конструкция:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM wall WHERE page='poll'
```

Comment: С каких пор эта конструкция выбирает всю строку?

Comment: Это выглядит как ответ (рекомендовать удаление не получится -- "выглядит нормально"), но ответ неправильный. Вам от меня минус, сниму если исправите ответ на рабочий.